# Why can't Spock mock Groovy and/or Grails methods with named arguments without explicit maps?

Tags: grails, groovy, spock

I'm in the process of unit testing some code which uses the Grails link generator to generate, well, links ;-). In the code I'm testing the following statement appears.

```
grailsLinkGenerator.link(mapping: "someUrlMappingName", id: someObject.id)
```

When looking at the source code for the interface `LinkGenerator` we see the following method signature.

```
String link(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Map params, String encoding);
```

Groovy treats a list of named arguments as a map, which is described [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Extended+Guide+to+Method+Signatures). This I understand. What I don't understand however is why the following (Spock) Mock doesn't work.

```
1 * factory.grailsLinkGenerator.link(mapping: "someUrlMappingName", id: someObject.id)
```

I have to explicitly put the named arguments in a map like the following example.

```
1 * factory.grailsLinkGenerator.link([mapping: "someUrlMappingName", id: someObject.id])
```

**Can anybody explain what's going on here? Is this a limitation of the Spock mocking library? Is there some other Grails or Groovy magic going on I don't grasp (yet)?**

Comment: The Spock interaction seems to be missing a value for `encoding`.

Comment: Stupid me! That makes sense. If I mock the DefaultLinkGenerator (with provided constructor arguments) and then mock the link method without the explicit map it throws the following exception when compiling:

`Error Compilation error compiling [unit] tests: unknown kind of argument list: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression@706ba7cf[org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.NamedArgumentListExpression@2bd640b2[org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MapEntryExpression@7f317c99(key: ConstantExpression[mapping], value: ConstantExpression[someUrlMapping])`

Comment: That previous stacktrace was shortened because of the limited amount of characters allowed in comments. I think it gets across the point though ;-).